# .htaccess настройка

Tags: .htaccess

На сайте все картинки стили и прочие **"публичные"** файлы лежат в специальной папке `public`. Но при обращении указан путь в корень сайта.
Пример: 
Обращение `mysite.ru/img/photo.jpg`
картинка находится `mysite.ru/public/img/photo.jpg`

Как настроить `.htaccess` таким образом, чтобы все запросы на файлы перенаправлялись в папку `public`, но при этом запросы вида `mysite.ru/` и `mysite.ru/test/test` перенаправлялись в `index.php` ?

У меня получилось что-то такое:

```
RewriteEngine on

<Files ~ "\.(.*)$">
    RewriteRule ^(.*) public/ [L]
</Files>

RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [L]
```

Но оно не работает (

Comment: можно сделать каталог `img` *симлинком* на каталог `public/img` и в конфигурации сервера разрешить следование *симлинкам*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
# запрос не начинается с папки public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/public\/
# чтобы обращение к index.php не перехватывалось
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/index\.php
# запрос на конце содержит расширение файла 2 или 3 символа
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.[^\/\.]{2,3}$
# дописать в начало запроса папку public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]

# запрос на конце не содержит расширение файла 2 или 3 символа
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[^\/\.]{2,3}$
# открыть index.php
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#RewriteRule .* /index.php [L]
```

Comment: С файлами работает, но если не файл на index не перенаправляет

Comment: @СтаниславДалинин, что значит не файл? В вопросе шла речь про файлы. Пример ссылок на которых работает и на которых не работает покажите.

Comment: Ваш код перенаправляет всё в /public/. Например, /img/photo.jpg работает, перенаправляет в  /public/img/photo.jpg, но если url к примеру такой /img/photo или  /blog то должно перенаправлятся в /index.php а у вас в /public/index.php

Comment: @СтаниславДалинин, понял и поправил. Добавил условие не перехвата index.php в первом редиректе.

Comment: Да всё чётко, красиво ) Вопрос только Что значит '[^\/\.]' и почему не '[a-z]'

Comment: @СтаниславДалинин, это вы можете по своему усмотрению поставить, какие символы допустимы в расширениях файлов. Я просто указал, что после точки должно быть 2 или 3 символа в конце url отличающиеся от точки и слеша. Можно вместо `[^\/\.]{2,3}` перечислить какие типы файлов хотите переадресовывать, например `(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css)`.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо ))

Answer (score 0):

можно пойти несколько иным путём:

#### вариант 1

если каталог `img` в корне не существует, его можно сделать *симлинком* на каталог `public/img`:

```
$ cd корень.сайта
$ ln -s public/img .
```

и в соответствующей секции в конфигурации *virtualhost*-а разрешить следование *симлинкам*, добавив в директиву `options` параметр `followsymlinks` (или убрав минус перед этим параметром, если но упомянут как `-followsymlinks`). пример:

```
<directory /путь/к/корню/вашего/сайта>
 options ... followsymlinks ...
 ...
</directory>
```

#### вариант 2

можно добавить *alias* в конфигурацию *virtualhost*-а. пример:

```
<virtualhost ...>
 alias /img /полный/путь/к/public/img
 ...
</virtualhost>
```